# How to connect Oracle DB Developer VM with java code (intellij)

Tags: java, oracle

Hi I'd like to write application which use my database in java. I have Oracle DB Developer VM where I keep my database and I'don't know how can I get url address to connect Virtual Box with my code in java.
I've read 'readme' and i saw something like that "try JDBC REST driver: sql HRREST/oracle@http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/"

I've tried to connect something like that but it does't work

```
public Connection connect()
{
    String url = "HRREST/oracle@http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/";
  
    Connection pol = null;
    try
    {
        pol = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "hr", "oracle");
        System.out.println("connected");
    }
    catch (SQLException throwables)
    {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }


    return pol;
}
```

EDIT:

errors:

```
maj 17, 2021 9:35:00 PM oracle.dbtools.jdbc.util.LogUtil log
INFO: oracle.dbtools.jdbc.orest.Driver:<clinit>:38:No Message
maj 17, 2021 9:35:00 PM oracle.dbtools.jdbc.util.LogUtil log
INFO: oracle.dbtools.jdbc.orest.Driver:<clinit>:45::ORest driver loaded
maj 17, 2021 9:35:00 PM oracle.dbtools.jdbc.util.LogUtil log
INFO: oracle.dbtools.jdbc.orest.Driver:acceptsURL:80:No Message
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for HRREST/oracle@http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at AplikacjaOrlace.connect(AplikacjaOrlace.java:14)
    at AplikacjaOrlace.main(AplikacjaOrlace.java:29)
```

[image]

Comment: ok I've already added

Comment: do you have the oracle jdbc driver in your classpath?

Comment: I've edited post and added screen with my drivers

Comment: That is meant to connect via sqlcli client.For Developer VM relevant [ports](https://prnt.sc/131uzzp) were forwarded.Look at this example [code](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database) or from Oracle [github](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) example code with `HR schema`